# How to delete data from table using php and Json?

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I am trying to put in a delete account option in my application, however when I try to delete the account I am not getting a respsonse from the web server.

Instead I get the error:

```
org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of
```

I have tried to change the request method to DELETE however I am not too familiar with android and databases so I am not sure if that would work.
I am not sure whether the problem lies with the php or the java code, when I run the debugger in android studio the String response returns:

```
response: ""
```

php:

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){


$id = $_POST['id'];

require 'conn.php';


  $sql = "DELETE * FROM Patients WHERE patientID='$id'";

if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){

  $result['success'] = "1";
  $result['message'] = "success";
  echo json_encode($result);

  mysqli_close($conn);


} else {

  $result["success"] = "0";
  $result["message"] = "Error!";
  echo json_encode($result);
  mysqli_close($conn);

}
}
 ?>
```

Java delete method:

```
 private void deleteAccount() {
        final String name = this.name.getText().toString().trim();
        final String lName = this.lName.getText().toString().trim();
        final String dob = this.dob.getText().toString().trim();
        final String email = this.email.getText().toString().trim();
        final String password = this.password.getText().toString().trim();
        final String passwordConf = this.cPassword.getText().toString().trim();


        final String id = getID;



        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_DELETE,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            String success = jsonObject.getString("success");
                            if(success.equals("1")){

                                Toast.makeText(EditAccount.this, "Account Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(EditAccount.this, "Error: "+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(EditAccount.this, "Error: "+error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                })



        {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("id", id);

                return params;
            }
        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

    }

}
```

I expect the toast to pop up and say account deleted but instead I get the error message stated at the top.

p.s. this is just a prototype so I am not worried about security at the moment.

Thanks!

Comment: You didn't define `$result = array()` in the PHP code which most likely is causing a notice text which is invalid json..

Comment: I have added the $result = array(); to my code but no luck I'm afraid, thanks!

Comment: Running the debugger now, the response String is now returning:  "{"success":"0","message":"Error!"}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever the issue might be, I am going to take a guess and say `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST')` is the root of your issue.

Your request may be sent wrong to the server and the `method` is not recognized as `POST` which would explain a `""` response since you do not offer an alternative to what should happen at the condition failing.

Send a bad request response (`400`) back and you will have the ability to troubleshoot this issue in your Java code... PHP is fine.

```php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') { /* ... */ }
else {
  http_response_code(400);
  // exit('Bad request method.');
  // or for a json response:

  echo json_encode([
    'success' => "0",
    'message' => "Bad Request Method used."
  ]);
}
```

---

Also, I have to say... Security should always be a concern... It does not take but a few more lines of code to filter the user request, and make your query a bit more secure via prepared statements. It's more of an issue of habits; one day you might forget a query here or there.